# Encrypt message in golang with ed25519 public key

Tags: go, encryption, openpgp

I am trying to encrypt a simple message in Golang 1.18 with my public opengpg ed25519 key, but I receive from the `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp` lib the error `unsupported feature: public key type: 22`.

The lib is marked as [deprecated](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44226) since last year and I don't know how I can encrypt a simple message in golang with my public key with alternative crypto libs.

Here is my example code which does not work. Maybe anyone can help me to find a solution.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/armor"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/packet"
)

const publicED25519Key string = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=i5Ul
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
`

func main() {
    message := "Hello World"

    publicGPGKeyReader := strings.NewReader(publicED25519Key)

    block, err := armor.Decode(publicGPGKeyReader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error decoding OpenPGP Armor: %v", err)
    }

    packetReader := packet.NewReader(block.Body)
    pkt, err := packetReader.Next()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading next block: %v", err)
    }

    key, ok := pkt.(*packet.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("Block is not a public key")
    }

    wc, err := openpgp.Encrypt(os.Stdout, []*openpgp.Entity{{PrimaryKey: key}}, nil, nil, nil)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to initialze a new encrypter: %v", err)
    }
    defer wc.Close()

    _, err = wc.Write([]byte(message))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to encrypt message: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it says in the deprecation notice, if you require PGP compatibility, then you should use a community fork of `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp` (or some other replacement if one becomes available).